# "The ones" or "those"?

Tags: pronouns

I recently corrected

> "ghettos, such as *the ones* found..." to
>
> "ghettos, such as *those* found..."

Was I correct, or are both versions right?

Comment: I'd say ***those*** is correct because you are referring to people(groups). ***ones*** is generally used for objects except in few formal structures like *One must think before he speaks*.

Comment: They're both correct.  The restriction in Fr0zenFyr's comment applies to actual persons, not objects _or collectives_ - though one has to avoid ambiguity when referring to people-groups! There is perhaps a nuance of pre-referencing in _the ones_ not hinted at by _those_ - "We came across many ghettos during our investigation. Some were beyond description, such as the ones ..."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They're both grammatically and semantically correct. They differ in style and register.

> "..ghettos, such as **the ones** found..." is verbose: two words versus
>   "..ghettos, such as **those** found..." one word.

You'll find both styles in formal academic prose and in informal prose. I prefer the second style and would make the same change were I editing a sentence with the first string in it.

I'm not sure which would occur more often in speech. I tend to speak the way I write (formal, generally grammatical correct, and, I've been told, in difficult vocabulary). Most people write like they speak, though.

There's no rule that forbids anyone from using **the ones** when talking about people. E.g.:

> I generally like girls in their late teens and early twenties, but **the ones** who belong to Chi Omega Tau are too poor to consider for marriage, **the ones** who belong to Phi Phi Phi, too intelligent to consider for a fun date, and **the ones** who belong to Zeta Beta Gamma, too muscular to consider for tennis opponents.

Here's a blog titled *[The Ones to Watch](http://www.theones2watch.com/)*. It's all about people, not videos or trains or enemy planes.

Comment: Nice answer. I googled your example ("I generally like girls...") but can't find it. It sounds like Woody Allen. Is it?

Comment: @HellishHeat: Thank you for the compliment, but the example is pure Bill Franke. I've watched a lot of Woody Allen movies, though. :-)

Answer (score 0):

"The ones" is best used when things or individuals share something in common but are not being members of or being united in one or the same group. Whereas "those" is best used when things or individuals share something in common and are members of or being united in one or the same group.

Comment: Hi and welcome to ELU. This question is over a year old, and it already has an accepted answer. Please make sure your answer will actually provide really helpful, additional detail before posting it.