# "those" VS "ones"

Tags: word-choice

In this sentence([origin](http://docs.spring.io/spring-hadoop/docs/2.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/springandhadoop-config.html)):

> When merging several properties, ones defined locally win.

Is it better to replace `ones` with `those`?

Possibly a duplicate : [the ones or those.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114834/the-ones-or-those)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can go wrong with either, they're both fairly similar in meaning. It just depends on what tone you're going for. Personally, I prefer `those`, because it sounds a little more casual and is easier to understand. `Ones` sounds more formal.

Comment: I'm with you :)

Comment: I think using ones is unclear unless modified to "the ones."  To my ear, a subordinate clause beginning with "ones" sounds like you're saying "one's."

Answer (score 0):

I believe that *ones* is bad to use when you can help it.

"One" is a singular item, so it makes sense to use "those" if it can be used correctly, rather than using "ones". Also stevesliva brings up a great point, when reading *one* might just confuse *ones* with *one's* in their mind for a bit before taking a second look.

Comment: Well, I actually think "the ones" can help clarify a plural subgroup when used instead of "those," but I always attach the article "the."