# those vs the ones

Tags: grammar

Would you choose the more appropriate sentence?

> We are open to cooperation with new companies as well as  *the ones* with good reputation

Or:

> We are open to cooperation with new companies as well as *those* with good reputation

Comment: This looks like the answer can be found at http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114834/the-ones-or-those

Comment: I saw it but I do not think this is of the same meaning that is why I decided to clarify. Thank you

Comment: Your're welcome, and I believe that the answer to the question addresses the problem quite nicely. I found it after I wrote my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the sentence with the word those is better, but that is personal preference. They are both grammatically correct. You could also say the companies instead of either those or the ones.